# how to measure the sensitvity between many variables in respect to another variable?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, t-test, p-value

I have 5 **meteorological variables** (i.e temperature, wind, humidity, sunshine, and Precipitation) that affect load forecasting. I need to measure the dependency & sensitivity of these parameters to each other with respect to electrical load . The number of samples roughly 1000 samples for each variable. After that I should determine the main dominant parameters affecting the load. Should I use correlation or T-test ?

As far as I know correlation measure of association, but paired t-test is a measure of difference. I guess that correlation could be tricky if there is a dependency ,but I'm not sure.

thank you in advance.

Comment: 5 variables and 1 dependent variable. What about sample size?

Comment: roughly 1000 samples for each variable.

Comment: Assume you have 5 meteorological variables (i.e temperature, wind, humidity, sunshine, and Precipitation).